# Stargazer change rownames

Tags: r, lm, stargazer

I wanted to change the rownames, but the function `covariate.labels` does not work here like it does using the normal `lm` function with stargazer.

When I try `covariate.labels` in the below function it changes the  column names of the coefficients functions ( estimate, std error,...).

```
stargazer(summary(lm(V1_V2$LF_FEV1_ProzentDif ~ 
                   V1_V2$Alter.x + V1_V2$Geschlecht.x + V1_V2$Reha_12V2 +
                    V1_V2$Medi__Antichol_Dif + 
                   V1_V2$Medi__LTRA_Dif + V1_V2$Med_LABA_ICS_LABA_Dif +
                   V1_V2$Medi_Omalizumab_Dif + V1_V2$Med_ICS_NEU_Dif +
                   V1_V2$Medi_Steroide_NEU_Dif + V1_V2$LF_FEV1_ProzentV1 ))$coefficients, digits=1)
```

Is there a function like `romwnames= c("a", "b"..)`?

Answer (score 1):

I would try Yuliia's answer. If it doesn't work, try to assign a `dep.var.labels` first. Then, you are to `covariate.labels = c("wow", "wow2")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try 
`covariate.labels=c("A","b","c")`